# Data left in memory and on disk after delete weaviate

Tags: weaviate

When using DELETE /v1/schema to delete the whole class towards weaviate, data is sometimes left on disk and  in memory but the schema is deleted. It is then not possible to retrieve the data and not to do another delete. So if I recreate the schema it is not possible to fetch the old data and a new delete to the new schema does not delete the old data. Have only encountered in a multi shard setup and sometimes only on one of two shards.

Is it possible through the api to do a hard delete in some way and not delete the storage catalog?

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue @gurgoles - can you provide a bit more information to reproduce the error? This might be helpful https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/tutorials/write-great-bug-reports.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Okey, I will try that. Happens a bit sporadically but it may also be something in my setup I suppose. Will try to be more detailed in the bug report